# Odoo - Dropdown search in related model

Tags: odoo-10

I've got the following model:
groups - partners
groups - vehicles

partners <- vehicles

Vehicles are related to partners (each partner can have multiple buses) via the x_partner_id field.

I would like to assign a partner and a bus to each group with the possibility to chose a bus from a different partner. The form looks like this:

```xml
<form>
    <sheet string="Groups">
        <group col="4">
            <field name="x_date_start" modifiers="{}"/>
            <field name="x_date_stop" modifiers="{}"/>
            <field name="x_partner_id" can_create="true" can_write="true" modifiers="{}"/>
            <field name="x_name" modifiers="{}"/>
            <field name="x_vehicle_id" can_create="true" can_write="true" modifiers="{}"/>
            <field name="x_groupcode" modifiers="{}"/>
            <newline/>
            <field colspan="4" name="x_stops_id" modifiers="{}"/>
            <newline/>
            <separator/>
        </group>
    </sheet>
</form>
```

Right now, if I type any property in the x_vehicle_id field on the form, I can find the bus I need. Can someone give me a hint, how to modify this field in the form to extend this search to other models related to the vehicles model? So, if I enter a partner name, I want to see only the buses from that partner.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood your question, you want to limit `x_vehicle_id` to ONLY show vehicles related to `x_partner_id`?

You need an onchange method for this. Something along the lines of

```
@api.onchange('x_partner_id')
def onchange_partner_id(self):
    return {'domain': {'x_vehicle_id': [('partner_id', '=', self.x_partner_id)]}}
```

(assuming `x_vehicle_id`'s model has a field called `partner_id`)

This will change the field's `domain` every time `x_partner_id` is changed and limit the choices.

**UPDATE**: I misunderstood the question.

If you want to search vehicles by partner's name you will have to override the `name_search` method.

```
@api.model
def name_search(self, name='', args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100):
    res = super(<classname here>, self).name_search(name, args, operator, limit=limit)

    # Search more results here and add them to res

    return res
```

You can see [how it's done in `product.product`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/product/models/product.py#L59).

Comment: No. Now I would like to enter (part of) the partner name, in the vehicle field and get the list of the partner's buses in the dropdown list. Similar as now, if I start entering part of the license plate, the list is narrowed to the matching buses.

Comment: I updated my answer. There's even a better example in the project module for overriding name_search: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/project/models/project.py#L726

Comment: Ok, thank you. Where shall I do this? This doesn't look like a form code :( I didn't write an extra module, just created a few models and views with the GUI.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible to do this without creating a custom module that overrides product's `name_search` method. Are you using Odoo SaaS or a self-hosted instance?

Comment: Self-hosted. The out-of-the box CRM, Fleet and Project modules have almost everything I need, I just need a few extra fields and forms that connect them. I guess, I need to override the search in the fleet module, I think, then.